# Magento: is there way to log when an Admin launches a manual re-indexing, and when it starts and ends?

Tags: magento, logging, indexing

I'm using Magento Community 1.6.1.0 and I want to track when our Admins start a manual re-indexing, and how long that reindex takes (i.e. when it starts & stops).  The output would be something like:

```
Reindex process name, Datetime, Admin User, Start/End
```

I think this would be valuable information to help optimise our data input strategy, to see which processes take a long time and who is kicking them off, and at what time of day.

I've worked with the Enterprise version's Admin Log but that doesn't capture all of it (and I'm not going to upgrade to Enterprise just for that). Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you would need to create a custom module that extend :

/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php

Update

```
public function reindexProcessAction()
{
    $process = $this->_initProcess();

    // start logger here and get admin user name

    if ($process) {
        try {
            Varien_Profiler::start('__INDEX_PROCESS_REINDEX_ALL__');

            $process->reindexEverything();
            Varien_Profiler::stop('__INDEX_PROCESS_REINDEX_ALL__');
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('index')->__('%s index was rebuilt.', $process->getIndexer()->getName())
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
                 Mage::helper('index')->__('There was a problem with reindexing process.')
            );
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(
            Mage::helper('index')->__('Cannot initialize the indexer process.')
        );
    }

     // stop timer and write information to db or file

    $this->_redirect('*/*/list');
}
```

and

```
public function massReindexAction()
{    
    // start logger here and get admin user name
    /* @var $indexer Mage_Index_Model_Indexer */
    $indexer    = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
    $processIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('process');
    if (empty($processIds) || !is_array($processIds)) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('index')->__('Please select Indexes'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($processIds as $processId) {
                /* @var $process Mage_Index_Model_Process */
                $process = $indexer->getProcessById($processId);
                if ($process) {
                    $process->reindexEverything();
                }
            }
            $count = count($processIds);
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('index')->__('Total of %d index(es) have reindexed data.', $count)
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, Mage::helper('index')->__('Cannot initialize the indexer process.'));
        }
    }
    // stop timer and write information to db or file
    $this->_redirect('*/*/list');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Will take a look at this and let you know how we get on with it.